# MongoDB - How can I use $elemMatch with multiple criteria

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB record that has the following record structure.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("547e29f2421aa9302705679a"),
    "runs" : [ 
        {
            "datetime" : "2014-04-2813:18:54.959579",
            "tag" : "v1.0",
        }, 
        {
            "datetime" : "2014-11-1122:45:13.841787",
            "tag" : "v1.1",
        }
    ],
    "person1" : "person1_id",
    "person2" : "person2_id"
}
```

Some of my records will have more or less `runs` , each with a different `tag`. I am trying to formulate a query that will tell me which records have a `run` with `tag=v1.1` but **not** a `run` with `tag=v1.0`.

I am just beginning to learn MongoDB, but I've come up with the query:

```
db.mycollection.find( { $and: [
  { runs : { $elemMatch : { tag : 'v1.1' } } },
  { runs : { $elemMatch : { $ne: { tag : 'v1.0' } } } },
]})
```

however, this still returns records with `tag=v1.0`. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. *Can anyone point me in the correct direction?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `$elemMatch` there, and can fire a direct `count()`. Use `$elemMatch` only if you want to `update` or `project` an array element.

```
db.mycollection.count({$and:[{"runs.tag":"v1.1"},
                    {"runs.tag":{$not:{"$eq":"v1.0"}}}]})
```

or a `find()`

```
db.mycollection.find({$and:[{"runs.tag":"v1.1"},
                    {"runs.tag":{$not:{"$eq":"v1.0"}}}]})
```

Comment: Even better than the solution I posted. Accepted!

Answer (score 1):

I found using the `$not` in the correct place does the trick.

```
db.mycollection.find( { $and: [
  { runs : { $elemMatch : { tag : 'v1.1' } } },
  { runs : { $not: { $elemMatch : { tag : 'v1.0' } } } },
]}).count()
```